# Error in confusionMatrix(test$RM, predict(modelFit, test))

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a confusion matrix and keep getting the following error:

**Error in confusionMatrix(test$RM, predict(modelFit, test)) :
could not find function "confusionMatrix"**

Sample data

V1. V2. V3. V4. V5. V6. V7. V8
-64 -56 -61 -66 -71 -82 -81 1
-68 -57 -61 -65 -71 -85 -85 2
-63 -60 -60 -67 -76 -85 -84 3
-61 -60 -68 -62 -77 -90 -80 4
-63 -65 -60 -63 -77 -81 -87 1
-64 -55 -63 -66 -76 -88 -83 1
-65 -61 -65 -67 -69 -87 -84 2
-61 -63 -58 -66 -74 -87 -82 3
-65 -60 -59 -63 -76 -86 -82 4
-62 -60 -66 -68 -80 -86 -91 1
-67 -61 -62 -67 -77 -83 -91 1
-65 -59 -61 -67 -72 -86 -81 1
-63 -57 -61 -65 -73 -84 -84 1

Below is my code:

```
set.seed(1)
row.number = sample(1:nrow(wifiDat), 0.25*nrow(wifiDat))
train = wifiDat[row.number,]
test = wifiDat[-row.number,]
dim(train)
dim(test)
lda.fit = lda(RM~WF1+WF2+WF3+WF4+WF5+WF6+WF7,data=train)
lda.fit
lda.pred <- predict(lda.fit, test)
names(lda.pred)
table(lda.pred$class, test$RM)
mean(lda.pred$class==test$RM)
sum(lda.pred$posterior[,1]>0.9)
modelFit<- train(RM~WF1+WF2+WF3+WF4+WF5+WF6+WF7, method='lda',preProcess=c('scale',   'center'), data=train)
confusionMatrix(test$RM, predict(modelFit, test))
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Did you load the `caret` package?

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano, thank you for the suggestion. After adding package caret, I was able to get confusion matrix to work, but I got another error message:               Error in lda(RM ~ WF1 + WF2 + WF3 + WF4 + WF5 + WF6 + WF7, data = train) : 
  could not find function "lda"

Comment: You probably did not load the `MASS` package.